# Display Attribute in Edit Product Back end Magento

Tags: product-attribute, attribute-set

Please help me!. I have an attribute "manufacture". How can i display this attribute into General tab in Edit Product Page ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to, `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribute Sets`, Select required attribute set.

Now Drag `manufacturer` attribute to `General` block, shown below :

[image]

Now click `Save Attribute Set`, you should be able to see `manufacture` attribute in `General` tab

Comment: Hi @Anil Suthar : Thank you for your reply. I did it but i can get it in General. I choose Default attribute set. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Make sure, the product you are editing is from Default attribute set ?

Comment: Sorry i'm newbie magento. How can i determine attribute set which display in product edit page ?

Comment: Go to edit product in admin. You can see the name of product at top. At the end of name you can see an attribut set name in braces `(ATTRIBUTESET_NAME)`. Also you can see this at products grid at column named `Attrib. Set Name`

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the desired attribute to all desired attribute sets by dragging it into the desired tab.  You can get to each individual attribute set edit form by clicking on the corresponding record in the Attribute Sets grid.

Comment: Hi @Luke : thank you for your reply. I drag this attribute set and drop it into General. But i can't find it.